# Picking out the differences between two vectors

Tags: c++, stdvector

Is there a way of comparing two vectors (called words and wordList) and picking out what was missing from one and outputting it?

For example, say words contains (cat, dog, parrot) whilst wordList contains (dog, parrot). The program would recognise that wordList does not contain cat despite the ordering and would output it.

How would I go about doing this? Any help given would be appreciated

Comment: Are you perhaps looking for [std::set_intersection](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_intersection) or [std::set_difference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_difference) ?

Comment: Do you know the idea behind unix command 'unique'?  Maybe std:unique is somewhat similar.

Comment: 'despite the ordering' is the crucial point. This problem gets much easier if you sort your vectors. If you want to keep the original ordering then copy your vectors and sort the copies. Either way sorting is required for a simple and efficient solution.

Comment: @john or sort a container of `std:: reference_wrapper<type>`, to get a sorted "view" without altering the original, if copying is expensive.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a brute force algorithm:

```
1. for each word, w, in words do
2.    search wordList for w.
3.    if w is found, process result.
4.    else call function for w not found.
5. end-for
```

Use `std::string` for your words.
To speed up the search, you could sort the `wordList`.
If you sort the `wordList`, you could use a *binary search*, which improves the speed.
Using a data structure, like `std::map` or a hash map or set, may also improve your program's speed.